# Bash scripting loop concatenate pipes / redirections based from names variable

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, grep, scripting

I have a command that produces a number of output lines that I later grep searching for.

Based on a past answer I know I can use a single long command and do all my filters concurrently:

https://superuser.com/questions/7448/can-the-output-of-one-command-be-piped-to-two-other-commands

```
command | tee >(grep filter1 >./filter1) >(grep filter2 >./filter2)
```

Now if only I could create a structure from my filter parameters that I can later decouple into that long command, then I could write a script that does the heavy lifting for me, like in the following shell pseudocode:

```
filters='filter1 filter2 filter3'
for filter in $filters; do
  SOMEHOW_STORE_REDIRECTIONS+=>(grep $filter > ./${filter})
command | tee >{SOMEHOW_DECOUPLE_STORE_REDIRECTIONS_VAR_INTO_LONG_COMMAND} | cat > /dev/null
```

Comment: `| cat > file` could be always replaced with `> file`. But since it is not related to the main question, I would suggest to remove redirection to `/dev/null` at all

Comment: Could you provide an example, how do you expect the script could be used? Do you suppose that _filter_ = "`grep` invocation" or "any shell command"? Note, that in former case each filter definition requires two separate parameters — the `grep` pattern and the filename to store filtered data, because not all `grep` patterns could be valid filenames. In your example "filter1", "filter2" and "filter3" are both patterns and filenames at the same time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to do them one at a time recursively:

```
filter() {
  if [ "$#" -eq 0 ]
  then
    cat
  else
    f="$1"
    shift
    tee >(grep "$f" > "$f") | filter "$@"
  fi
}

printf '%s\n' {foo,bar}{0..100} | filter foo bar r3
```

However, this adds a number of extra buffers and steps, so alternatively, you can make careful use of `eval`. This is OK because the filenames are carefully being escaped:

```
filter() {
   cmd="tee "
   for f in "$@"
   do
     cmd+=">(grep -e ${f@Q} > ${f@Q}) "
   done
   eval "$cmd"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with `eval`:

```
# usage xfilter filter_spec filter_args...
xfilter() {
    local cmd flt=$1; shift
    printf -v cmd " >($flt)" "$@"
    eval "tee $cmd"
    wait
}

$ echo paa | xfilter 'sed %q' s/a/e/g s/a/o/g
paa
pee
poo

$ tgrep(){ grep "$1" > "./$1"; }
$ printf '%s\n' foo bar | xfilter 'tgrep %q' foo bar
foo
bar
$ grep . foo bar
foo:foo
bar:bar
```

And no, there's **no problem at all** with `eval` if used judiciously. After all, bash will call `eval` on each line of your script separately, take a second to think about it.